# Dataframe Output is not concatenating the way I want it to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx1xq.png)

If you see the above image, output file has multiple rows. I want everything in single row with the right headers

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

companies = ["IBM"]

def fetchData(func, symbol):
    key = "key"
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={func}&symbol={symbol}&apikey={key}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    return data

dfs = []

#COMPANY OVERVIEW

for company in companies:
        ov = fetchData("OVERVIEW", company)
        dfo = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ov, orient='index').transpose()
        dfo = dfo.drop(columns = ['AssetType', 'Description', 'CIK', 'Sector', 'Address', 'FiscalYearEnd',
        'LatestQuarter', 'PEGRatio', 'BookValue', 'DividendYield',
        'RevenuePerShareTTM', 'ProfitMargin', 'OperatingMarginTTM',
        'ReturnOnAssetsTTM', 'ReturnOnEquityTTM', 'RevenueTTM',
        'GrossProfitTTM', 'DilutedEPSTTM', 'AnalystTargetPrice',
        'PriceToSalesRatioTTM', 'EVToRevenue','EVToEBITDA',
        '50DayMovingAverage','200DayMovingAverage', 'SharesOutstanding',
        'DividendDate','ExDividendDate'])
        print(dfo)
        dfs.append(dfo)

#INCOME STATEMENT

for company in companies:
        inc = fetchData("INCOME_STATEMENT", company)
        dfi = pd.DataFrame(inc["annualReports"])
        dfi = dfi.drop(columns = ['reportedCurrency'])
        dfi_2022 = pd.DataFrame(dfi.iloc[0]).transpose()
        dfi_2021 = pd.DataFrame(dfi.iloc[1]).transpose()
        dfi_2020 = pd.DataFrame(dfi.iloc[2]).transpose()
        print(dfi_2022)
        dfs.append(dfi_2022)

#BALANCE SHEET

for company in companies:
        bal = fetchData("BALANCE_SHEET", company)
        dfb = pd.DataFrame(bal["annualReports"])
        dfb = dfb.drop(columns = ['reportedCurrency'])
        dfb_2022 = pd.DataFrame(dfb.iloc[0]).transpose()
        dfb_2021 = pd.DataFrame(dfb.iloc[1]).transpose()
        dfb_2020 = pd.DataFrame(dfb.iloc[2]).transpose()
        print(dfb_2022)
        dfs.append(dfb_2022)

#CASH FLOWS

for company in companies:
        cf = fetchData("CASH_FLOW", company)
        dfc = pd.DataFrame(cf["annualReports"])
        dfc = dfc.drop(columns = ['reportedCurrency'])
        dfc_2022 = pd.DataFrame(dfc.iloc[0]).transpose()
        dfc_2021 = pd.DataFrame(dfc.iloc[1]).transpose()
        dfc_2020 = pd.DataFrame(dfc.iloc[2]).transpose()
        print(dfc_2022)
        dfs.append(dfc_2022)

#EARNINGS

for company in companies:
        earn = fetchData("EARNINGS", company)
        dfe = pd.DataFrame(earn["annualEarnings"])
        dfe_2022 = pd.DataFrame(dfe.iloc[1]).transpose()
        print(dfe_2022)
        dfs.append(dfe_2022)

#CONCAT DFs

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

I tried the above code and then concatenated the individual dataframes

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx1xq.png)

If you see the above image, output file has multiple rows. I want everything in single row with the right headers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffill` and `drop_duplicates` symbol to keep one row per symbol:

```
df = (df.ffill().drop_duplicates('Symbol', keep='last')  # keep one row per symbol
        .replace('None', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1)) # remove null columns
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Symbol                             Name Exchange Currency  ... dividendPayoutCommonStock proceedsFromIssuanceOfLongTermDebtAndCapitalSecuritiesNet proceedsFromRepurchaseOfEquity reportedEPS
4    IBM  International Business Machines     NYSE      USD  ...                5948000000                                         7804000000                            -407000000        9.12

[1 rows x 94 columns]
```

Comment: I'm still facing issue when pulling data of multiple companies